# I cannot open .xlsx file during append data

Tags: java

I want to open an xlsx file,during write data,but it throw exception,and i want to open it like opening txt file during append data.

while opening xlsx file during write data it throw below exception,
how to ignore this exception and data written completely such as append data to txt file and opening file during write data and not throw any exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: output.xlsx (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at com.html2pdf.writeoutput.WriteOutput.writeOnXLSX(WriteOutput.java:52)
    at com.html2pdf.main.ReadPNFromXLSX.readXLSXFile(ReadPNFromXLSX.java:256)
    at com.html2pdf.main.ReadPNFromXLSX.main(ReadPNFromXLSX.java:59)
```

Can any one given success help.

Comment: Please post more information like your code and error.

Comment: what exception you are getting post your code so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you open your `output.xlsx` file? Through Java or with MS Excel itself?

Comment: i open xlsx file on desktop machine  at the same time  i write to the same xlsx.